# how to store, retrieve and change values using java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to save item number, CO number, CO line, qty inside an array then I'm saving that array inside array list. For some records inside array list I want to retrieve that record based on CO number and CO line and change the qty of it.
What is the easiest way to do this? Maybe storing inside array and storing those arrays inside Array list in not a good idea. I'm doing this development inside an integration system. Therefore there is limitations like can only use single Java class file etc.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
//Loop arraylist

for (int i = 0; i < g_COList.size(); i++) {
        //Get array
        String[] CO = (String[]) g_COList.get(i);

        coNumber = CO[0];
        coLine = CO[1];

        if (coNumber.equals("567780000") && coLine .equals("10")) {
            g_COList.set(i, new String[] { "45", "567780000", "10", "5"});
        }

    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you place here your code?

Comment: My last post was short because it was just incomplete due to internet connection , you can check my suggestion now

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is using a class , creating a class CO that will store your attributes { item number , CO number , CO line ... etc }

Then each time you wanna add an element to your arraylist it will be an object containing your informations , like this :

```
ArrayList<CO> list = new ArrayList<CO>();
CO object = new CO(.....); // filled with your informations
list.add(object);
```

---

**To extract COnumber and COline :**

```
for ( CO object : list ) {
    System.out.println( object.getCOnumber() ); // use getters to extract
    System.out.println( object.getCOline() );
    object.setQty( ... ); // use setters to modify ( ... : you new qty )

   // so here the idea of retreiving objet with certain COnumber or COline 
   //seems easy
   if ( object.getCOnumber() == " .. " && object.getCOline() == " .." ) {
       object.setQty( ... );
   }
}
```

Comment: what if I want to check CO number and CO line and change the qty? Same as I did I have to loop right?

Comment: The COnumber and COline are first and second item right , so you'll simply have to get the first and second CO object , and extract the wanted informations from them , i'll edit my answer to show you how @RasangaAbeykoon

Comment: I think @Karam u misunderstood my question. Every CO object has those CO number, CO line, item and qty. The requirement is loop through the array list which contains COs and retrieve a CO which contains particular CO number and CO line and change the qty of that CO object.

Comment: ah okey i get it now , so it's easy to do it , i ll edit my answer to show you how @RasangaAbeykoon

Answer (score 1):

You can store plain array within your ArrayList, that's absolutely fine and you can use C style for loop for the sake of performance as this code would be faster in comparison to storing data in objects inside the list and then traversing the array list. If you're not operating on large data set the I would recommend you to leverage Object Oriented programming in your code. Following would be the code that you can write. \n

### Your Item class

```
@lombok.Getter
@lombok.Setter
@lombok.Builder
public class Items {

    private long itemNumber;

    private long coNumber;

    private long coLine;

    private long quantity;

    }
```

### This is how you would traverse the List of Items

I am assuming that getData() method would give you list of items and then will work on it. I am creating another List of items with your new values in it.

```
    ArrayList<Items> list = getData();

    List<Items> newList = list.stream()
            .filter(items -> items.coNumber == 567780000L && items.coLine == 10L)
            .map( items -> Items.builder()
                           .itemNumber(items.itemNumber)
                           .coNumber(items.coNumber)
                           .coLine(items.coLine)
                           .quantity(45L) //new quantity
                           .build())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can also made changes to the source stream but it's not advisable, you should avoid modifying state of source of stream. From non-interference section of stream package documentation we can read that: [Non Interference doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference)

Anyway, code is as below

```
list.stream()
            .filter(items -> items.coNumber == 567780000L && items.coLine == 10L)
            .forEach(items -> items.setQuantity(45L));
```